# Win32 message queue gets flooded when rendering with OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl

I encapsulated the the Windows API's CreateWindow around a class I call GLWindow, to which I render images using OpenGL.
It took me some time, I even encapsulated the message queue, so basically my `main` function looks like that:

```
int main()
{
    GLWindow win;
    win.create("OpenGL Window", false, 1600, 800, -1, -1, true);
    win.hideCursor();
    win.moveMouseToCenter();

    init(); //initialize some opengl stuff

    bool quit = false;
    WindowEvent ev;

    while (!quit) {
        if (win.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            if (ev.type == ev.WindowClosed || (ev.type == ev.KeyboardKeyPressed && ev.keyboardKey.key == Keyboard::Key::Escape))
                quit = true;
            else
                handleEvent(ev);
        }

        updateCamera(&win);

        render(&win);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `render` function obviously takes the most time, and it causes the window procedure function to get flooded with messages, which eventually creates a delay in the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages and because of that the camera update is delayed as well. (inside `updateCamera()`)

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: You could change the `if (win.pollEvent(ev))` to a `while (win.pollEvent(ev))` that way you'll handle **all** messages generated during the last frame.

Comment: "*it causes the window procedure function to get flooded with messages*" - that doesn't sound right...

Comment: @selbie yeah it does. there are usually more than a single window event between two frames...

Comment: What are these messages?  Because if we know *why* your message queue is growing, we can figure out a way to make it not do that.

Comment: Also, show your code that abstracts out the windows message pump (GetMessage, PeekMessage, DispatchMessage) - which I assume is in your GLWindow class.  That is, show your implementation for pollEvent and handleEvent.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios silly me... switching `if` to `while` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: WHY was this downvoted? It seems like a perfectly reasonable question. What is wrong with SO? It seems like many people are (apparently?) afraid to post an answer, instead using the comment section to suggest a solution or possible solution?

Comment: @Manius: At a guess, because it doesn't contain a [mcve]. Still, the core issue is very visible, and - to me anyway - this question looks a lot more valuable than lots others.

Comment: It does, and yeah it doesn't have such an example. But that is a LOT more work usually (unless it's an easy/beginner question), and here's an example where it wasn't even needed. The "high standards" thing here is actually causing more problems than it solves, IMO.

Comment: @Manius: I'd disagree with that. The fact that producing a [mcve] is hard work doesn't mean that it shouldn't be done. This is part of the reason, why Stack Overflow is such a valuable resource: Self-contained questions, that tell the whole story, not just the pieces the OP finds relevant (which is usually a wrong assessment). This question, though, holds enough information for anyone who's done any sort of realtime rendering to answer, as well as for those, looking for help. Still, it is an outlier, not the norm.

Comment: We're probably just not going to agree on this. You admit this question is "good enough", contradicting the need for such an example. The frequency of how often that happens isn't relevant IMO. What is relevant is that if we stick to the "SO rules" as gospel, this question would be deleted or downvoted (like it was?) - and that doesn't help anyone. Isn't helping people the whole point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is, that your code handles a single message in between rendering frames. Instead, it should drain the entire message queue. This can be as easy as replacing `if` with `while` for the message polling expression. It's probably also a good idea to `break` immediately out of the loop in case you hit the termination condition.

```
while (!quit) {
    while (win.pollEvent(ev))
    {
        if (ev.type == ev.WindowClosed || (ev.type == ev.KeyboardKeyPressed && ev.keyboardKey.key == Keyboard::Key::Escape))
        {
            quit = true;
            break;
        }
        else
            handleEvent(ev);
    }

    updateCamera(&win);

    render(&win);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your OOP abstraction is rubbish. And, as the comments point out, you havn't included it.

`win.pollEvent(ev)` strongly implies that you are polling events for a single window only. This is wrong - message loops must pump messages for ALL the windows on a thread.

Its also entirely unclear what `handleEvent()` does - I hope it calls `TranslateMessage / DispatchMessage` to ensure the message arrives at your GLWindows window procedure.

So now, we can't see your WindowProc. Does it handle WM_PAINT at all? Does it handle it correctly? The inclusion of `updateCamera` and `render` in the message implies you might not be handling your painting requirements properly. While this is a pattern used to achieve high frame rate rendering, writing a game loop that pumps messages correctly is hard, and you would probably be better served (for now) getting the window to update on a timer, and to do painting by triggering WM_PAINT messages by calling InvalidateRect. You have to get this right anyway so you can handle window resizing, minimizing and being covered by other windows elegantly.

Comment: *"message loops must pump messages for ALL the windows on a thread"* - Plus messages that aren't posted to any window, i.e. thread messages.

Comment: TranslateMessage / DispatchMessage are handled in win.pollEvent(). handleEvent() is just a local function in main.cpp in which I test stuff. Why do I need to handle WM_PAINT? I've been doing fine without doing so.

Comment: Here are the implementations of pollEvent and the winProcedure functions in GLWindow: [https://pastebin.com/R5fhjMMy](https://pastebin.com/R5fhjMMy)

Comment: Also why is my abstraction rubbish? I've been told that abstracting the windows api is a wrong move basically, (although it makes the code a lot nicer and easier) but why aside from that..?

Comment: @Pilpel: The system will invalidate part of a window, when it gets uncovered. This triggers generation of a `WM_PAINT` message. If your `WM_PAINT` handler doesn't validate the invalid region (e.g. by calling `BeginPaint` or `ValidateRect`), the system continues to trigger generation of `WM_PAINT` messages. The situation isn't as bad as it sounds, though: `WM_PAINT` messages aren't actually posted to the message queue, but generated on demand, so the queue will not fill up with `WM_PAINT` messages.

Comment: It won't fill up with them, but it will continue to generate them in preference to fetching any queued messages. @Pilpel - step 1 in improving the abstraction would probably to be to add a GLThread class that handles thread things such as message loop processing.

Comment: @IInspectable I think I got it but can you link an example?

Comment: @ChrisBecke Do you mean something like this? https://pastebin.com/7xuZivVe

Comment: @Pilpel: Details are documented: [The WM_PAINT Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145137.aspx). While this relates to the native window (to which the OpenGL render context is attached), it is usually ignored in code that continuously renders the entire scene. The native window still does get invalidated when obscured portions become visible, or the window is resized, which triggers generation of `WM_PAINT` messages. In your setup the only adverse effect of not validating the invalid region is one superfluous `WM_PAINT` message per frame, that's passed to the message handler.

Comment: event handling should surely remain in the window class.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: *"it will continue to generate [WM_PAINT messages] in preference to fetching any queued messages"* - `WM_PAINT` messages are low-priority. The system won't generate a `WM_PAINT` message, unless the message queue is empty (see [If my WM_TIMER handler takes longer than the timer period, will my queue fill up with WM_TIMER messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141204-00/?p=43473)).

Comment: Hey, look at that. And there I had incorrectly remembered that windows prioritized painting.